# paramiko no acceptable kex algorithm while ssh to el capitan

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I"m using python 2.7 and paramiko 1.16

While attempting an SSH to el capitan, paramiko throws the exception `no acceptable kex algorithm`. I tried setting kex, cyphers in sshd_config, but sshd can't be restarted for some reasons.  I tried some client side fixes, but upgrading paramiko did not fix the problem.

Comment: Please describe the fixes you tried and the other failure emssages.

Comment: I've upgrade paramiko to 1.20.0, but still having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround from another stack overflow issue by putting the following cipher/mac/kex settings to sushi_config:
    Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
    MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1
    KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1